# asp.net mvc - setting meta tags & page title

Tags: asp.net, viewmodel, meta-tags, page-title

I have my asp.net mvc project setup which passes strongly typed view models to every view using a BaseViewModel. The base view model includes information such as page title & meta tag information.

Is there a fast & simple way to use this information from my ViewModel to set this information in my master page?

At the moment i have to include code such as this below in every view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<meta name="keywords" content="<%= Model.MetaKeywords %>" />
<meta name="description" content="<%= Model.MetaDescription %>" /></asp:Content>
```

I can't think of a way to set this info automatically other than the way i am doing it currently, but just looking to optimise this repeated html code.

Thanks!
Paul

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make the above code part of your master view and pass the Title, Keywords, and Description using ViewData dictionary from Controller to View.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ActionFilter in CodeCampServer](http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4755c1386bff#src%2fUI%2fHelpers%2fFilters%2fAddPageInfoForMasterPage.cs) as an example of another take on how to insert the title.